# C# Convert or compare int to (unsafe) byte*

Tags: c#, int, byte, unsafe

**Original Scenario**

I massively misunderstood my own code, and this scenario is invalid.

> This is way out of my normal wheelhouse, so I'm going to explain best
>   I can.
>
> I have a user-set color code. Example:
>
> ```
> int R = 255;
> int G = 255;
> int B = 255;
> ```
>
> And I have a lot of large images where I need to check the color of
>   pixels at certain sets of coordinates against the user-set color. I
>   can successfully get the `byte*` of any pixel in an image, and get the
>   values I expect.
>
> I do this using `BitmapData` from `Bitmap.LockBits(...)`. My
>   understanding is that locking will be important to performance
>   reasons. There will be a great many instances of this being used
>   across a very large collections of images, so performance is a major
>   consideration.
>
> For those same performance reasons I'm trying to avoid converting the
>   retrieved pixel-colors represented by unsafe bytes to integers - I'd
>   much rather convert my int to a byte one time and use that for the
>   likely millions of pixels this will be run against each time it is
>   invoked.
>
> However... I cannot figure out how to get any of my user-set integers
>   into an unsafe byte (`byte*`) and compare it to the unsafe byte
>   retrieved from a pixel.

The unsafe byte (`byte*`) was the 8-bit pointer of the data of the pixel (at least, that's how I understand it) but I am getting the individual colors as regular old bytes.

```
byte* pixel = //value here pulled from image;
pixel[2] //red value byte
pixel[1] //green value byte
pixel[0] //blue value byte
```

So I don't need to convert my `int`s to unsafe bytes ...pointers?..., just a simple `Converter.ToByte(myInt)`.

---

**The real question**

But since I think this is still possibly a valid question outside my scenario, I'm going to leave this part up for someone to answer and hopefully help someone in the future:

How do you take any given `int` in C# and compare it to an "unsafe byte" pointer '`byte*`'?

Comment: There are no unsafe bytes by the way, `byte*` is a pointer to (normal) byte(s), the unsafe thing (in the sense that it requires the `unsafe` keyword) is using pointers

Comment: You can get a color from the bitmap .             Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            Int32 rgb = color.ToArgb();

Comment: @harold I'm starting to think I fundamentally don't understand what I'm trying to do here... not primarily a C# dev so this is different for me.

Comment: @jdweng yes, though for performance reasons I believe I should avoid `GetPixel`, at least that's what the documentation I've read is leading me to believe.

Comment: If you lock with the ARGB format you could even use `int*` and compare a whole pixel at the time instead of treating the R G and B separately

Comment: @harold fantastic suggestion, but given that I'm going to end up testing in a range per color (not shown in my example) it won't quite work here

Comment: @harold, that is absolutely nice advice-hack-

Comment: How about following :            IntPtr ptr = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            Size size = bitmap.Size;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size.Height * size.Width];
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, bytes);

Comment: Note that if you have some data in memory, processing it on a byte-per-byte basis is the worst thing you can do performance-wise. Modern CPUs are 64bit or 32bit "wide" with registers of equivalent bit-width (not considering registers of SIMD extensions). Getting data from memory as ints (or longs) will be much faster, even under considerations of necessary bit-shifting and -masking, as 4/8 bytes can be loaded into a register once (= one cache or memory lookup) and those shift/mask ops can be done within a register. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Trying to access each byte from the memory individually will likely require at least a cache-lookup for every single byte, which is much slower than holding multiple bytes in a register and using shifting/masking ops to access their bits. (Depending on what you really want to do and minimum CPU specs required for your project, SIMD extensions such as SSE might be worth to look into)

Answer (score 1):

You would just want to dereference the byte pointer and compare it to the integer.

```
unsafe void Main()
{
    byte x = 15;
    int y = 15;
    Console.WriteLine(AreEqual(&x, y)); // True
}

public unsafe bool AreEqual(byte* bytePtr, int val) {
    var byteVal = *bytePtr;
    return byteVal == val;
}
```

Comment: Totally doable, but my concern here was around performance - I'm converting likely millions or billions of pointers to vars on each evocation, or just three ints to pointers. Though I believe I may be massively misunderstanding how pointers work, I usually dev front-end or at least not this deep on the back-end.

Comment: @RandyHall You could convert an integer to a pointer, but ultimately if you want to compare the value that they point to, you will need to dereference them. If you compare the pointers, they are going to be unequal unless the point to the same address. If you add `Console.WriteLine(&x == &y);` to the above code, you would be comparing the pointers, and the result would be false. They point to different addresses, so they are not equal. `Console.WriteLine(*(&x) == *(&y));` would be true, as you're dereferencing and comparing the value they point to.

Answer (score 0):

Let us open a open a bitmap and process each pixel

```
//Note this has several overloads, including a path to an image
//Use the proper one for yourself
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(_image);

//Lock(and Load baby) 
BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);

//Bits per pixel, obviously
byte bitsPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat);

//Gets the address of the first pixel data in the bitmap.
//This can also be thought of as the first scan line in the bitmap.
byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();

for (int i = 0; i < bData.Height; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bData.Width; ++j)
    {
        byte* data = scan0 + i * bData.Stride + j * bitsPerPixel / 8;
        //data is a pointer to the first byte of the 3-byte color data
        //Do your magic here, compare your RGB values here 
         byte R = *b;     //Dereferencing pointer here
         byte G = *(b+1); 
         byte B = *(b+2); 
    }
}
//Unlocking here is important or memoryleak
b.UnlockBits(bData);
```